# how to perform same mechanism like how SSAS cube does on redshift?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssas, amazon-redshift

We have SSAS cube running pulling the data from a datawarehouse which slices and dices the data and give it to reporting team.Now that we have decided to move the data to redshift.We want the same functionality as SSAS cube does on redshift.How do we achieve this?

Comment: Why would you choose to move to a platform *before* checking it has all the functionality you require?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift does not natively provide cube/slice/dice capabilities.

This is normally provided by software products that sit "on top" of a database.

There also seems to be information available about using Amazon Redshift with SSAS Cube:

- [How do I start OLAP cubes with Amazon Redshift? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-start-OLAP-cubes-with-Amazon-Redshift)
- [SSAS Multidimensional Project: How to connect to Redshift Database](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf0206aa-a8d4-4661-b15b-6b4e63a18f81/ssas-multidimensional-project-how-to-connect-to-redshift-database?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

(I got them from a Google search.)

Comment: can i connect SSAS cube to AWS redshift?

Comment: I'm not sure, but those linked pages suggest that you can. Feel free to do more Internet searches to find out!

Answer (score 0):

AWS Redshift like any OLAP database doesn't provide that functionality. You need your BI/Viz. tool to do that itself. 
e.g. Quicksight has SPICE, Qlik has qvd's, SSAS has Tabular etc.